# bootstrap 4.1 card stacked in column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

On my page I have two columns, and the right column should hold a dynamic number of bootstrap cards, vertically stacked. The card should have the image on the left, and text on the right.

The cards shouldn't be too big, they are profile cards from users. I can get the image on the left side of the card, but the cards do not align, or take on the width of the column they are in (they are shorter).
What I have so far:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 teams teams-overview">
    ... some content
    </div>
   <div class="col-sm-3 teams team-details">
      <div class="row">
         <!-- ... this is where I want the cards -->
         <div class="card">
            <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
               <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
               <p class="card-text">Some quick example text. </p>
               <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       ....here will be more cards added.
    </div> 
</div>
```

My expected outcome would be something similar to this:
[image]

In this screenshot, it shows that the cards do not have the length of the column. It should maintain its relative positions if the window size changes. Also, if the length of the text changes, the images are not aligned vertically. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you please add more explanation about expected output ?

Comment: added a screenshot of what I currently see on screen

Comment: kindly share demo code of this demo to fix it, your code in question is working well